# Including page settings when creating a translation request

Tags: translation, kentico

I'm currently running a Kentico 9 instance to support a large website that is available in multiple languages. I'm leveraging the built-in Translation and Translation Services modules to send content to our translators.

When I create a submission ticket for a new item to translate and look at the XLF that gets generated, there are `<trans-unit>` elements for all page type fields marked as translatable as well as one for the `DocumentName` field. These fields then get translated by our vendor and re-imported into the CMS.

My question is, can I include other document system fields in this XLF?

Specifically I'm looking to include the `DocumentPageTitle`, `DocumentPageKeyWords`, and `DocumentTags` fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible to do via the built-in Translation service because these fields are marked as without translation. Example, for DocumentPageTitle:[image]

Comment: Thanks anton-grekhovodov! This turned out to be the case. However, after some additional digging I discovered that this flag is able to be modified through the API. I know this is a risky move as it could change during upgrades but it's a field that I really need to include in our page translation requests.